# Do water blocks that would fit a MacBook Pro cpu socket exist?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature, customization

From what I've read, when you buy a water cooling system you match stuff depending on your cpu socket or gpu type. Can that be done for MacBook Pro's?

*Update 
I have a rMacBook Pro 13" Early 2015. From just looking at the insides I can see the heatsink has four screws an inch and a half apart from each other. I didn't want to add too many details of my project. It just lends itself to criticism instead of trying to answer a question. What I thought I could do is buy an extra bottom plate and fit a hole for a water cooler and mount it to my cpu.

Picture of logic board: https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/AQu64Mt2TOCnRGJ5.huge

Comment: You are gonna have to be a LOT more specific as to your make and model and what EXACTLY you are trying to accomplish. You might want to review the disassembly info on ifixit.com for various MacBooks. Most have little or no room in them and CPUs/GPUs are rarely socketed. Instead being mounted directly to the systemboard.

Comment: Thanks I added some detail, and I think this is a picture of the cpu https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/AQu64Mt2TOCnRGJ5.huge

Comment: Why do you want to liquid cool a MacBook Pro?

Comment: Honestly you may be better asking this on a manufacturers website or one specifically about water cooling. Not sure what you think you are going to get water cooling an already sufficiently cooled computer. It's not like you can overclock a Mac...

Comment: Because fans spinning at 6000+ rpm are loud and sufficient seems subjective, but thanks.